What did Jesus really mean when he promised the thief paradise?
Luke 23:43

'I tell you the truth, today you will be with me in paradise'

What meaning is conveyed by Jesus here because scripture says that none of the fathers have gone to heaven ever since they slept
2 Peter 3:4

"For ever since the fathers fell asleep, all things are continuing as they were from the beginning of creation"

I interpret to sleep to mean death, so if the fathers such as Abraham died and haven't gone to heaven.
Saint John also taught that no man has ascended into heaven save for the Son of Man
John 3:13

And no man hath ascended up to heaven, but he that came down from heaven, even the Son of man which is in heaven.

what did Jesus mean he said those words to the thief at the right?

See my answer to exegesis - Jesus answered him, "I tell you the truth, today you will be with me in paradise." Luke 23:43 - Christianity Stack Exchange.
